# Why does React Native Return A String Equivalent Of A Boolean?

Tags: react-native

I am evaluating some variables and using the result to conditionally render elements.

This is the evaluation

```
const condition = this.props.badgeCount > 0
```

and using the result like this

```
<View>
  {condition && (
    <View>
      <Text>
        {this.props.badgeCount}
      </Text>
    </View>
  )}
</View>
```

And RN fails with the error

> text strings must be rendered within a text component

and works well when I change `condition` to

```
const condition = Boolean(this.props.badgeCount > 0)
```

So, clearly the results returned back are something like `"true"` or `"false"`.

My question is why is this, because that is clearly an evaluation that should return a boolean and also is there a way other than the one I am using, to solve this problem?

Comment: N.B. `Boolean(foo)` has the same effect as `!!foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because what you are doing there is an inline if statement. Any string that is not an empty string, `null`, or `undefined` is a truthy value (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

You can easily test this by going in your browser's console and executing:

```
console.log('someString' ? true : false);
console.log('' ? true : false);
```

You can solve your problem by doing `!!condition` which will co-erce the string value to a boolean and thus not trigger the `text strings must be rendered within a text component` error:

```
<View>
    {!!condition && (
        <View>
        <Text>
            {this.props.badgeCount}
        </Text>
        </View>
    )}
</View>
```

More information on `!!` (NOT NOT) in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/784946/3061857